# Remove an item from object based on existence in second object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following 2 objects. How can I remove items from `listProposalProducts` that don't have a `coverageLineId` that matches an `id` from `coverageLinesSelectedItems`? In this example, I want to remove item 1 from `listProposalProducts` because an id of 2 does not exist in `coverageLinesSelectedItems`. I think I'm looking for the opposite of the pop() method but I'm not sure how to get the correct index to splice out of `listProposalProducts`.

```
let listProposalProducts = [
    0: {productId: 101391, coverageLineId: 1}, 
    1: {productId: 101591, coverageLineId: 2},
    2: {productId: 151391, coverageLineId: 3}
]

let coverageLinesSelectedItems =  [
    0: {id: 1, itemName: 'Medical'},
    3: {id: 3, itemName: 'Vision'}
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `Array.filter` combined with `Array.some` to filter the results. E.g.

```
let listProposalProducts = [
    0: {productId: 101391, coverageLineId: 1}, 
    1: {productId: 101591, coverageLineId: 2},
    2: {productId: 151391, coverageLineId: 3}
]

let coverageLinesSelectedItems =  [
    0: {id: 1, itemName: 'Medical'},
    3: {id: 3, itemName: 'Vision'}
]

let requiredResult = listProposalProducts.filter(
  item => coverageLinesSelectedItems.some(
    cov => cov.id === item.coverageLineId
  )
);
```

This keeps only the products whose `coverageLineId` matches the `id` of a `coverageLinesSelectedItems` element.

Answer (score 1):

A simple straight forward implementation would be:

```
listProposalProducts.filter((it) => coverageLinesSelectedItems.find((other) => other.id === it.coverageLineId))
```

If the objects are larger, you might want to compute a map from the lookup object.

```
const lookup = {}
coverageLinesSelectedItems.forEach((it) => {lookup[it.id] = true;})
listProposalProducts.filter((it) => lookup[it.coverageLineId])
```